# Error on line 121 in fs.js when trying to run Unit test in VSC

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, testing, mocha.js, chai

I installed Mocha tests and Chai to VSC and wrote a simple function to test it. 
file1:

```
module.exports = function add(x,y) {
    return x + y
}
```

file2 (unit tests)

```
const { expect } = require('chai');
const add = require('../exersize');

describe('add numbers func', () => {
    it('add function is a function', () => {
        expect(typeof add).to.equal('function')
    });
});
```

When I hit f5 to see the result from the unit test in the console, I see an error in "fs.js" online 121

[image]

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: I assume you installed mocha globally? It seems like vscode connot find a .mocharc.json in the directory `c:\..\Desktop\123\ `.
How have you installed mocha?

Comment: I think I have. This is from the Terminal:

C:\Users\b85m\Desktop\123>npm install mocha
npm WARN 123@1.0.0 No description
npm WARN 123@1.0.0 No repository field.

+ mocha@6.2.1
added 91 packages from 516 contributors and audited 301 packages in 7.394s
found 0 vulnerabilities


C:\Users\b85m\Desktop\123>npm install chai
npm WARN 123@1.0.0 No description
npm WARN 123@1.0.0 No repository field.

+ chai@4.2.0
added 7 packages from 20 contributors and audited 309 packages in 1.476s
found 0 vulnerabilities

Comment: I found the file in: Desktop\123\node_modules\mocha\lib\

Comment: As noted in the [documentation](https://mochajs.org/#configuring-mocha-nodejs) the .mocharc.json is used to configure your mocha instance. Have you tried to copy it to your working directory? So to the path `c:\..\Desktop\123\ `
I think you have a local mocha installed in your directory, as you mentioned, but you also have a gloablly installed mocha, which is choosen by vscode and therefore needs the config file inside the working directory?

Comment: How can I globally install Mocha?
I copied the file in the dir /123/ and now I get the error: https://ibb.co/Zc6KKJ9